# Why does Scanner not go to the next line when reading a file?

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner, file-handling

I am using the following code to read a file:

```
Scanner fscanner = null;
try {
    fscanner = new Scanner(new File("spotify.txt"));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
}

while(fscanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = fscanner.nextLine();

    Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(line);
    Album album = new Album();

    if(lineScanner.next().equals("CD")) {
        album.setComposers(lineScanner.next().replaceAll(",", "'s"));
        album.setAlbumName(lineScanner.useDelimiter(",").next().trim());
        album.setYear(lineScanner.next().trim());
        fscanner.nextLine();

        String c = album.getAlbumName();
        String a = album.getComposers();
        String y = album.getYear();

        System.out.println(a+" "+c+" "+y);

    }
    else if(lineScanner.next().equals("SONGS")) {
        ArrayList<String> songs = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> songDur = new ArrayList<String>();

        lineScanner.nextInt();

        songs.add(lineScanner.useDelimiter(",").next());
        songDur.add(lineScanner.next());

        album.setSongs(songs);
        album.setSongDurations(songDur);

        for(int i=0, j=0;i<songs.size() && j<songDur.size();i++, j++)
            System.out.println("SONG "+i+" "+songs.get(i).toString()+ " "+songDur.get(j).toString());

        System.out.println(album.showSongs());
        System.out.println(album.showSongDurations());

    }
    else if(lineScanner.next().equals("ADD")) {
        Adds adds = new Adds();

        adds.setCompanyName(lineScanner.useDelimiter(",").next().trim());
        adds.setDuration(lineScanner.next());
    }
}
```

The file looks something like this:

```
CDS
CD U2, Songs of Innocence, 2014
SONG 1, The Miracle, 4:15
SONG 2, Every Breaking Wave, 4:12
SONG 3, California, 4:00
SONG 4, Song for Someone, 3:47
CD Coldplay, Parachutes, 2000
SONG 1, Don’t Panic, 2:17
SONG 2, Shiver, 5:00
SONG 3, Spies, 5:19
SONG 4, Sparks, 3:47
SONG 5, Yellow, 4:27
CD ImagineDragons, Night Visions, 2015
SONG 1, Demons, 3:14
SONG 2, Monster, 2:57
ADDS
ADD ING Bank, 0:20
ADD Bol.com, 0:15
ADD Albert Heijn, 0:30
ADD Specsavers, 0:15
ADD Kruidvat, 0:10
ADD MediaMarkt.nl, 0:20
```

The problem is I am getting  `NoSuchElementException` at the line `else if(lineScanner.next().equals("SONGS"))`.

I simply don't know why is this happening, when the code actually execute with going to the next line as it should, if I remove both of the `else-ifs`.

The output it gives is exactly as expected but not when I introduce those `else-ifs`.

How do I fix it?

Comment: Each time you call next(), it goes to the next() element. So if (s.next() ...) { ... } else if (s.next() ...) { ... } } calls next() twice if the first if condition is false. Use a variable.

Comment: Note also that you're skipping a line in the "CD" case, because you call `fscanner.nextLine()`. So the first song of each CD will never be looked at.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException what should I do to avoid that?

Comment: @DodgyCodeException also currently it does not enters the `else if`, when I put a variable for checking the word, it does not gives exception but does not go into `else if`

Comment: @Manhar just don't call `fscanner.nextLine()` in that "if" block. You should only ever call nextLine once in the while loop. Then the next line will be read at the next iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first line, you're going to read the first token and check if it's equal to `CD` ; then if it's not, you're going to try reading another token (from the same line) to check if it's equal to `SONGS`, which will raise an error on the first line since there are no more tokens to read from that line.

You will want to read the first token of the line into a variable before your if/else if and reference that variable in your conditions so that they all check against the first token of a line.

As a side note I'd avoid using two different scanners ; if I'm not mistaken you're incorrectly skipping a line in the `CD` branch when you call `fscanner.nextLine();`, which would only be useful if you used the same scanner everywhere (to discard the unused rest of a line). In that case the nextLine call should be placed after the if/else if to avoid duplication.

Comment: I introduced a variable but it still does not work, it does not gives the exception, however it does NOT enters `else if`, ever, I checked it by putting a `System.out.println("enters")` but it does NOT execute. Can you help me finding out the reason for this?

Comment: @Manhar Your text file does not contain a line that says "SONGS".

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Ah, I couldn't spot that, Thank you :). However it now gives `InputMismatchException`

Comment: That would be a terrific occasion to learn to use a step-by-step debugger ;) Seriously, search for "<your IDE> debugger", it'll change your life

Comment: @DodgyCodeException found it, I had an unnecessary `nextInt()`. Thank you :)

Comment: @Aaron Sarcasm at its best, *laughs* but the problem is that I am currently using a shit IDE in a totally messed up computer in my lab, so it would be difficult to know where in hell is the debugger and does it work or not... Anyways, thanks a lot :)

Comment: That wasn't sarcasm, sorry if I made it appear as such. It sucks not to be able to debug, good luck with your task !

Answer (score 0):

Check with your `lineScanner` first if it has any element left to dissect. Then reference the return variable of `lineScanner.next()` with a new variable so you do not have to call `lineScanner.next()` every time the if-else checks, because this method will jump to the next word every time you call it. Not very obvious, though.

```
Scanner fscanner = null;
    try {
        fscanner = new Scanner(new File("src/spotify.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    while(fscanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = fscanner.nextLine();

        Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(line);

        while(lineScanner.hasNext()){
            //Trim the word
            String word = lineScanner.next().trim();
            System.out.println(word);
        }
    }
    //Do not forget to close it
    fscanner.close();
```

Comment: No need to trim. The linescanner will discard whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

@Arron gave you the reason why.

Now Maybe this might help I believe it's faster and better than the scanner

```
int count = Files.lines(Paths.get(text_File_Location)).count(); //count number of lines in text file without any loop

 Path path = Paths.get(*text_File_Location, Name or URL*);

               for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
               {   
                    //It read exactly what we need
                    String line = Files.readAllLines(path).get(i);

                    //lets say u have data in text file in this format
                    //SONG,MUSIC,YEAR   Separated by comma


                    String everything[] = line.split(",");
                    String song = everything[0];
                    String music = everything[1];
                    String year = everything[2];

               }
```

Comment: This is highly inefficient because if the file contains 1000 lines you will open, read and close the file 10000 times, each time looking at just one line.

Comment: I might be wrong but I believe it takes whole text file in memory and then read it.
I think it's never open or closes text file. It's don't even read line by line. it's work amazingly well for few thousand lines but idk about 10- thousand.
Maybe it gives OUT OF MEMORY EXCEPTION. but also file.txt files are only a few hundred KB's even with 10- thousand line.

Comment: What I mean is that every time you call `Files.readAllLines(path)`, it actually reads those lines from the disk. And you are calling this method repeatedly, inside a for loop. Why not call it just once, and assign the returned value to a variable, before you enter the for loop?

Comment: @DodgyCodeException  Onc you run _Files.readAllLines(path)_  you get the file from disk and it gets stored in memory (like Uploading the whole book in the brain). And when you call it again in the loop it doesn't read from disk but from memory, _which is super fast_. Once that file in memory you can't delete or edit that text file externally. But with a scanner, It's first open file from disk and read each line 1 by 1 from disk (like reading a book) you can make changes to text file externally while the scanner is doing it job. it's a bit slow and Sometimes it might get corrupted while reading

Comment: This is not how `Files.readAllLines` works. It opens the file, creates a `List<String>`, reads the entire contents of the file into that list, and then closes the file. The next time you call it, it creates another `List<String>` and does exactly the same as before. Between calls of `Files.readAllLines()` you are free to modify or even delete that file. Now typically operating systems will cache disk access so that reading from a certain file multiple times won't actually read from the disk surface, but that sort of caching is part of the OS and not Java.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge with me really appreciated :)